# Tensorflow generate random values unexpected behaviour

Tags: tensorflow

I want to generate a random Vector and don't understand tensorflows results....

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

some_test = tf.Variable(
    tf.random_uniform([20], -1.0, 1.0, dtype=tf.float32))
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)
random = sess.run(some_test)
print(random)
```

gives me this:

```
[             nan              nan              nan              nan
              nan              nan              nan              nan
              nan   3.57331108e-43   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -3.05175781e-05
  -1.70141183e+38  -1.70141183e+38  -1.70141183e+38  -1.70141183e+38]
```

Comment: Well, that may be hard to reproduce... It works by me :P

Comment: You just copied over this code and the result is as expected? Well then it's even more confusing...

Comment: Yes. If I were you I'd try to extract `a = tf.random_uniform...` and see if `sess.run(a)` also gives these strange results.

Comment: Interesting... this somehow seems to be not working on my machine only since I tried it on 2 other machines and it works... Without the Variable the results are the same! I am officially confused right now.. Maybe my Tensorflow version has a bug..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay this is very confusing but the reason it did not work was that I was running some other Tensorflow Code in parallel. After I stopped this code the random generation works as expected. I doubt this is expected behaviour though.

If I use `with tf.device('/cpu:0'):` it works on my machine even if other code is running. Using gpu:0 gives the strange numbers, when tensorflow uses the GPU.

Also I tried to reproduce this on different machines and I couldn't. This means even with other tensorflow code running (same code, all on GPU etc..) selecting devices everything worked fine.